# cannot execute RUN mkdir in a Dockerfile with space in directory name

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create a file in C drive while building docker image and using command as below

```
RUN mkdir "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Passport RPS"
```

but it throws error:

```
Step 6/6 : RUN mkdir "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Passport RPS"
 ---> Running in ab58c6f2948d
[91mmkdir : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\Microsoft'.
At line:1 char:76
+ ... e = 'SilentlyContinue'; mkdir C:\Program Files\Microsoft Passport RPS
[0m[91m+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[0m[91m    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [mkdir], ParentContainsErro 
[0m[91m   rRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,mkdir
```

Tried above command with forward as well as back slash.

I have tried multiple other command as below:

```
ENV PATH_WITH_SPACE "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Passport RPS"
RUN mkdir $[PATH_WITH_SPACE]

RUN mkdir ["C:\Program Files\Microsoft Passport RPS"]
```

Can you please help me with appropriate command?

Comment: where you are trying to make the dir, in host or image? please post your dockerfile

Answer (score 6):

Came across same problem. None of the answers worked for me.
I finally got it working by escaping space with `

```
RUN mkdir "C:\Program` Files\Microsoft` Passport` RPS"
COPY . "C:\Program` Files\Microsoft` Passport` RPS"
```

Another approach is to use Shell, and declare escape explictly

[While the JSON form is unambiguous and does not use the un-necessary cmd.exe, it does require more verbosity through double-quoting and escaping. The alternate mechanism is to use the SHELL instruction and the shell form, making a more natural syntax for Windows users, especially when combined with the escape parser directive](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#shell)

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/nanoserver
SHELL ["powershell","-command"]
RUN New-Item -ItemType Directory C:\Example
ADD Execute-MyCmdlet.ps1 c:\example\
RUN c:\example\Execute-MyCmdlet -sample 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the space, some like:

```
RUN mkdir "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ Passport\ RPS"
```

Or using the `JSON format`:

```
RUN ["mkdir", "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\ Passport\ RPS"]
```

[**note:**](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#run) using `JSON format` is necessary to escape backslashes. This is particularly relevant on Windows where the backslash is the path separator.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried both command and both throws error :               RUN ["mkdir", "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\ Passport\ RPS"]                                             
 ---> Running in 7cfaf9384302

 ... $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [mkdir, C:\\Program Files\\ ...
Missing ] at end of attribute or type literal.

Answer (score 0):

We can  use PowerShell command to create folder with spaces.

Try this:

```
RUN powershell -Command New-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Passport RPS' -ItemType Directory
```

It Works !!!